# How do you write a list of struct vectors using Apache Arrow's Java Libs?

Tags: java, apache-arrow

I've been struggling for a few days now, trying to write a list of struct vectors using Apache Arrow.

I'm basically trying to construct something along the lines of the following:

```
[[{"key1", "value1"},{"key1", "value1"},...],[{"key1", "value1"}, {"key1", "value1"}...]...]
```

I've tried numerous variations, but here's one version of what I think should work below, for a list of struct vectors where each struct vector contains a collection of several varchar & dateday fields, as well as one int field:

```
ListVector listVector = (ListVector) root.getVector("units");
listVector.allocateNew();

UnionListWriter listWriter = listVector.getWriter();

for (int i = 0; i < allUnits.size(); i++) {
    listWriter.setPosition(i);
    listWriter.startList();

    BaseWriter.StructWriter structWriter = listWriter.struct("unit");
    StructVector structVector = 
          (StructVector) structWriter.getField()
                                     .createVector(allocator);
    structVector.allocateNew();

    // using this alternative below, I can see the StructVector filling up, but still nothing in the ListVector
    // StructVector structVector = 
    //       (StructVector)listVector.getChildrenFromFields().get(0);
    // structVector.allocateNew();
    // BaseWriter.StructWriter structWriter = structVector.getWriter();

    ArrayNode units = allUnits.get(i);

    // "accn", "form", "fp", "fy", "type" -> field names of 'varchar' type
    for (int x = 0; x < units.size(); x++) {
        structWriter.start();
        structWriter.setPosition(x);

        JsonNode unitNode = units.get(x);

        for (String varCharFieldName : UNIT_VARCHAR_FIELDS) {
              bytes;
             String varCharVal = unitNode.get(varCharFieldName).asText();
             byte[] bytes = varCharVal.getBytes();
             try(ArrowBuf tempBuf = allocator.buffer(bytes.length)) {
                tempBuf.setBytes(0, bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                structWriter.varChar(varCharFieldName).writeVarChar(0, bytes.length, tempBuf);
             }
        }

        // "end", "filed" -> field names of 'dateday' type
        for (String dateFieldName : UNIT_DATE_FIELDS) {
            LocalDate date = 
                  LocalDate.parse(unitNode.get(dateFieldName).asText(), ISO_LOCAL_DATE);
            structWriter.dateDay(dateFieldName)
                        .writeDateDay(Long.valueOf(date.toEpochDay()).intValue());
        }

        structWriter.bigInt("val").writeBigInt(unitNode.get("val").asInt());
        structVector.setIndexDefined(x);
        structWriter.end();
    }

    structVector.setValueCount(units.size()); 
    listWriter.endList();

}

listVector.setValueCount(allUnits.size());
```

I can see that the structVector is populating with data for a given 'unit' struct vector, but the writes do not propagate to the list of 'unit' struct vectors, the 'units' list field itself.

Below is a gist of a Google Colab notebook that will run the example, more or less.  It's better to take that code and run it in an IDE of your choice with the maven dependencies also specified in this notebook.

https://gist.github.com/gmsharpe/52aee837db9ebcacaf87a7ac07667bac

Comment: Is it possible to (a) add the code required to make this example runnable and (b) include the version of Arrow that you're using?

Comment: @L.Blanc - Sorry that I've re-created this comment several times.  I changed the associated gist to reflect something that at least runs.  It's not super pretty.  It is a Google Colab notebook with enough code that should be able to copy into your IDE, or run in Google Colab with the IJava kernel. IDE is probably better for debugging purposes.  
   https://gist.github.com/gmsharpe/52aee837db9ebcacaf87a7ac07667bac

Comment: @L.Blanc Arrow Version => 8.0.0  Details are in the Google Colab Notebook, too.

Answer (score 1):

I removed `structVector` and `structWriter.close()` from your `listWriter`-loop, so that it now populates the `units` array. Maybe you can continue from here:

```
ListVector listVector = (ListVector) root.getVector("units"); 
UnionListWriter listWriter = listVector.getWriter();
listWriter.allocate();
listVector.allocateNew();

List<ArrayNode> allUnits = nodes.stream()
                                .map(n -> (ArrayNode)(n.get("units").get("USD")))
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());

for (int i = 0; i < allUnits.size(); i++) {
    listWriter.setPosition(i);
    listWriter.startList();

    BaseWriter.StructWriter structWriter = listWriter.struct();

    ArrayNode units = allUnits.get(i);

    // "accn", "form", "fp", "fy", "type"
    for (int x = 0; x < units.size(); x++) {
        structWriter.start();
        JsonNode unitNode = units.get(x);

        for (String varCharFieldName : UNIT_VARCHAR_FIELDS) {
            byte[] bytes;
            if (varCharFieldName.equals("type")) {
                bytes = "USD".getBytes();
            } else {
                String varCharVal = unitNode.get(varCharFieldName).asText();
                bytes = varCharVal.getBytes();
            }
            ArrowBuf tempBuf = allocator.buffer(bytes.length);
            tempBuf.setBytes(0, bytes);
            structWriter.varChar(varCharFieldName).writeVarChar(0, bytes.length, tempBuf);

        }

        // "end", "filed"
        for (String dateFieldName : UNIT_DATE_FIELDS) {
            LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(unitNode.get(dateFieldName).asText(),
                                              DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);
            structWriter.dateDay(dateFieldName).writeDateDay(Long.valueOf(date.toEpochDay()).intValue());
        }

        structWriter.bigInt("val").writeBigInt(unitNode.get("val").asInt());
        structWriter.end();
    }
    listWriter.setValueCount(units.size());
    listWriter.endList();
}
listVector.setValueCount(allUnits.size());
root.contentToTSVString();
```

Comment: After the suggested edits, the individual struct vectors in the list are still not populating.  See 'fieldVectors' #6 in the image linked here:  https://ibb.co/x3KbKzC